# The application was unable to start correctly (0xC0000056). Click Ok to close the application

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013

I am developing a C++ app in Visual Studio and get this error when I go to debug - it never makes it to `main()`.  Googling for this error code doesn't help - in fact, most return hits are trojan horse websites.

Dependency Walker doesn't show anything funny. All DLLs are found on the path, and all are 64 bit as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out, one of the Windows DLLs that I am attempting to load has been marked for deletion by an installer that I installed earlier today. I had ran an update to TortoiseGit, which required replacing in-use system DLLs and requested a reboot (which I declined).

The error code 0xC0000056 found a hit here: http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/E/95EF66AF-9026-4BB0-A41D-A4F81802D92C/[MS-ERREF].pdf

> 0xC0000056 STATUS_DELETE_PENDING
>
> A non-close operation has been requested of a file object that has a
>   delete pending

After rebooting, I was able to debug my code.